# What is the fastest way to send data from WCF to a Silverlight Client?

Tags: silverlight, wcf

Here is a code snippet I am using. Feel free to suggest a better way. I wouldn't mind serializing the dataset to JSON and putting it back together on the other side, using something other than a dataset, or anything else you guys come up with. These results need to be shown in a listbox on the other side. Also, I would rather stay away from binding for now.

```
string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Local"].ToString();
        try
        {
            SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection();
            DataSet ObjDataset = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter objAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

            objConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

            SqlCommand getStudies = new SqlCommand("UWG.getCourses", objConnection);
            getStudies.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


            objConnection.Open();
            objAdapter.SelectCommand = getStudies;
            objAdapter.Fill(ObjDataset);

            return ObjDataset;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by fastest? I guess you are not looking for the answer "get a better network card"...

Comment: "Fastest" meaning most efficient, not as bulky as datasets, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the structure of whatever it is your sending but sending it as almost anything other than a dataset will probably be quicker.

Will a `List<string>` do the job?

Comment: It may be as simple as a few strings all the way up to a PDF.

Comment: Well you need to be more specific then, as the answer is different for both of those different examples you just gave. At the end of the day for objects your structure is going to be fixed and serialised so keep them as simple as possible, for files then you might want to just link to the file on the webserver, if your data is going to be dynamic then a dataset might be appropriate but there is no "best way" to send any data at all.

Answer (score 0):

Check out WCF RIA services.  You can still make that ado.net call and map the results to poco's to be returned to SL.  If you can use entity framework you can export the procedure and return complex types.

Comment: Thank you. I'm considering using the entity framework as well.

Comment: This is a good resource if you're limited to calling procs. http://thegrayzone.co.uk/blog/tag/wcf-ria-services/